# What happens if I receive a refund on a credit card with $0 balance?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

Let's say I make a purchase on a credit card. Months pass, and the card is eventually paid off. For whatever reason, I am then issued a refund on one of my past purchases. What happens? Do they send me a check?

Comment: Mhoran's answer below is right, but I'll ask, why not just charge a few normal purchases, gas, groceries, essentials, to clear the balance.

Comment: I double-checked the purchase in question, and thankfully I bought it with my bank card, not a credit card. But specifically, it was a pair of Lady Gaga tickets, which should implicitly answer your above question.

Comment: Not so much. If you're implying the tix were so expensive it would take a long time to charge that amount, ok. For us, no single purchase is likely to have that become an issue. But I understand, especially for a single person not buying $800/mo in groceries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They will credit your account and it will be applied to future purchases. If the credit card is not used for several months, they will send you a check or transfer it to your bank account.

Some people on this site have actually considered sending money to the credit card company in advance, so that the amount that can be charged is temporarily inflated. Keep in mind they will eventually refund the money. Plus you will not earn interest on the refund.

Comment: That's what I do with my credit card. It has a limit of $1000 because I'm an international student and had to actually deposit $1000 with my bank to get the CC. If I want to spend more (plane tickets, outdoor gear :D) I just "pre-charge" the CC account.